# Randomly select fraction of numbers in array, add/subtract some percentage of their original values, and rewrite array

Tags: python, random

I'm reading in an array of numbers `arr` from a csv file (1000+ entries). I figured out a way to replace a user-specified fraction of these numbers `err_frac` with random values drawn from a uniform distribution. For example:

```
err_frac = 0.2
swap_count = math.floor(err_frac * len(arr))
swap = np.random.uniform(low=np.amin(arr), high=np.amax(arr), size=swap_count)
arr.flat[np.random.choice(len(arr), swap_count, replace=False)] = swap
```

Now I'd like to take a randomly chosen fraction of these numbers and add or subtract some user-specified percentage of its original value. For example, if both percentages were 20%, the script would:

(a) randomly select 20% of the numbers in the original array

(b) if the chosen number was greater than the mean of the dataset, subtract 20% of its original value

(c) if the chosen number was smaller than the mean of the dataset, add 20% of its original value

(d) rewrite the modified values to a new array

Seems easy enough but I'm running into a mental block here. I tried something like this, but it's failing miserably:

```
for nz in range(1, len(arr)):
    nzc = nz - 1
    if arr[nzc] > 0.5 * np.amax(arr):
        swap = arr[nzc] - err_frac * arr[nzc]
        arr.flat[np.random.choice(len(arr), math.floor(arr[nzc]), replace=False)] = swap
    elif arr[nzc] < 0.5 * np.amax(arr):
        swap = arr[nzc] + err_frac * arr[nzc]
        arr.flat[np.random.choice(len(arr), math.floor(arr[nzc]), replace=False)] = swap
```

Ideas?

Comment: 1. I hope you have an IDE like visual studio code so you can debug your logic interactively instead of staring at it, sometimes that helps you get unblocked. 2. what is the origin of arr.flat and its interface? Is it your "new" array? The replace=False is confusing. 3. Suggest toss "nzc" and "nz" and just write "index" instead. 4. for index in range(len(arr)). 5. Truncate your data down to 5-10 rows instead of 1000 so you can debug more easily. 6. You have a less than, but not a corresponding >=, just have >, that could cause oddness. 7. Did arr.flat start as a copy of arr?

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. 2. Yes, the arr.flat line is supposed to overwrite all the original entries with the modified values. replace=False does sound confusing, but it's just there to ensure that np.random.choice picks unique values. 3-4. Done, this worked great, thanks. 6. Fixed, this helped a lot. 7. arr.flat is basically a relic of working with a 3D array, I kept it around because it would still work for 1D. My problem now is that it's replacing every single entry instead of just selecting 20%, and the standard deviation of the new array is super small (around 1 vs. 13 originally).

Comment: OK, can you edit and post your new code? Right now I'm thinking from looking at the current logic which either way, seems to me likely to change every element whether it is above 0.5 OR below 0.5. It think it should be more like if criteria(): swap(), and criteria() makes it so that 20% or 50% of the time, a swap happens.